# Need to move/rearrange SharePoint blogwebparts to the top dynamically when new post are published

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have several blog webparts on an SharePoint startpage. Need to make new blogposts stand out. Was thinking of rearranging the newly updated blog webpart to the top of the page. First in line...

Any ideas? been toying with the idea of making this work in clientside/frontend, without backend -> no deploying from a VS solution.

So any jquery phantoms out there :)

Comment: you said you want to make Blog web part to be top of the page ? Or a Blog Post ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to do any coding at all, you can easily use the Content Query Part to pick up the latest blog post - there are several examples out there including this one:

http://blog.henryong.com/2008/06/15/how-to-customize-the-content-query-web-part-xsl-to-aggregate-blog-posts/

That said there are additional ways to do it using the Client Object Model and/or a sandbox solution using REST or the OOB web services. The way blogs work, the latest post is always the 'front page' item; you need only get the latest from the POSTS library. Now while a Sandbox solution requires Visual Studio, it is deployed by uploading directly to the site (like Office 365) - no server access is required.

If you want to be even more 'slick', remember that the Site Type indicates that it's a blog - so you could scan the current sites and pick up each blog/latest post as you go allowing you to aggregate them all automatically.

I have a web part that does this that we'll be posting to codeplex but as you mentioned, that won't be of any help to you in that environment.

David Sterling - http://davidmsterling.blogspot.com - http://www.sterling-consulting.com